# CSS Isolation not working on project converted from .net5 to .net6

Tags: css, blazor, .net-6.0

I am using Visual Studio 2022. I have a Blazor server application that I created about a year and a half ago in .net5. I recently converted it to .net6 although I did not change any of the code. I simply changed the target framework and it has all been working fine. I never used CSS Isolation when it was .net5 but I want to use it now. I created a .css file (CheckInQuestion.razor.css) for one of my .razor files (CheckInQuestion.razor) and added the link reference for the scoped css file to my _host.cshtml file at the bottom of the  section.
`<link href="Hub.App.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I can see the scoped css file in the obj folder like I would expect

[image]

When I run the application, the html elements in the component have the scope reference as well.

[image]

However, the css file cannot be found so it does not apply the css.
[image: 404 Not Found Error Console]

Incidentally, I created a new Blazor .net6.0 project using Visual Studio 2022 and the CSS isolation works exactly how it is supposed to.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what is preventing my application from finding the scoped css file when I run it? It does not work on localhost or my development server.

Comment: Is the project that's running the web site *Hub.App*?  BTW it should work, so there's something wrong somewhere!

Comment: Yes, the assembly name is Hub.App

Comment: Can you show a full mage of your project structure in your question?